# Dynamically creating inline keyboard buttons telegram api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

I am trying to send buttons to my telegram bot using the telegram bot api. For now, for creating the buttons, I have to hard code the values in the fields but lets say I want to create the inline keyboard buttons dynamically through an array and passing the array index and the array values as parameters. How should i go about it ?
 This is what I tried so far.

```
  var menu =["Nightclub","Parks","Restaurants","Telecom","Internet"];
    var options = {
                    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
                        inline_keyboard: [
                            [{ text: 'Some button text 1', callback_data: '1' }],
                            [{ text: 'Some button text 2', callback_data: '2' }],
                            [{ text: 'Some button text 3', callback_data: '3' }]
                        ]
                    })
                };
```

Lets say I want to pass the data in the menu array dynamically inside my options. How do i go about it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood you well.

We gonna use here the [Array.map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) function to create one array using menu array.

```
  var menu = ["Nightclub", "Parks", "Restaurants", "Telecom", "Internet"];


  var options = {
       reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
            inline_keyboard: menu.map((x, xi) => ([{
                text: x,
                callback_data: String(xi + 1),
            }])),
      }),
  };
```

---

Gonna result to :

```
    {
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
        inline_keyboard: [
          [{
            text: 'Nightclub',
            callback_data: '1'
          }],
          [{
            text: 'Parks',
            callback_data: '2'
          }],
          [{
            text: 'Restaurants',
            callback_data: '3'
          }],
          [{
            text: 'Telecom',
            callback_data: '4'
          }],
          [{
            text: 'Internet',
            callback_data: '5'
          }],
        ],
      }),
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try too using a simple for loop:

```
var keyboard = [];
var menu = ['Nightclub', 'Parks', 'Restaurants', 'Telecom', 'Internet'];

for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
  keyboard.push([{'text': menu[i], 'callback_data': (i + 1)}]);
}

{
  'reply_markup': JSON.stringify({
    inline_keyboard: keyboard
  })
}


/* The result will be:
{
  'reply_markup': JSON.stringify({
    inline_keyboard: [
      [{'text': 'Nightclub', 'callback_data': '1'}],
      [{'text': 'Parks', 'callback_data': '2'}],
      [{'text': 'Restaurants', 'callback_data': '3'}],
      [{'text': 'Telecom', 'callback_data': '4'}],
      [{'text': 'Internet', 'callback_data': '5'}]
    ]
*/
```